# Flow created to check if the Group Member are Similar to the User in the Flow

Tags: queue, salesforce, record, salesforce-flow

Flow is been called through a Process Builder, and it passed the string of a user to the Process Builder to check if some certain user resides in the Queue or not.

I have found out the Queue Member which is the `UserorGroupId`. But the problem here is the Decision in the Flow seems to give me an error:

> User.UserOrGroupId because it hasn't been set or assigned.

So I have search out it says that you have to first check if the `UserOrGroupId` 
is NULL or because it is the lookup field.

But still, I am getting this problem I will be very thankful if you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got my Answer

But the problem here is the Decision in the Flow seems to give me an error User.UserOrGroupId because it hasn't been set or assigned

This error comes if you try to access a field which is null
AND
If you try to access a Field **which is not selected from the selected variable in the Loop** in my case I haven't selected the UserOrGroupId from the selected variable that's why it's was giving me this error